# Power BI matrix grand totals wont add up

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and facing this issue with a Power BI report grand totals of these columns won't add up. Any help is much appreciated, below are the formulas

```
Rolling 3 Months =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Deliveries[NetRevenue] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        Deliveries[DeliveryDate],
        MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] ) - 90,
        MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] )
    )
)
```

```
Prior 3 Months =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Deliveries[NetRevenue] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        Deliveries[DeliveryDate],
        MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] ) - 180,
        MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] ) - 90
    )
)
```

Screenshot of the result
[image: screenshot of the results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because `MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] )` is not the same for every row.

The maximum is evaluated within the local filter context, not over the entire `Deliveries` table (or the subset of the table that matches your filter settings).

I'm guessing you probably want to define a variable to use as your date rather than calculating it (potentially) differently for each row in your matrix. E.g.

```
Prior 3 Months =
VAR LastDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate] ), ALLSELECTED ( Deliveries ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Deliveries[NetRevenue] ),
        DATESBETWEEN ( Deliveries[DeliveryDate], LastDate - 180, LastDate - 90 )
    )
```

You might be able to use `TODAY()` instead of that `LastDate` calculation, depending on your particular situation.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks a ton!